# PROC SQL UPDATE - Efficiency

Tags: sql, arrays, loops, sql-update

I need to make this code more efficient (please see below). What the code is doing is updating the master data set 'consolidated' with values from 'means' only if observations in 'consolidated' is missing. This goes through and updates 16 variables.

Is there a way to make this more efficient such as creating a loop through the 16 variables?

```
proc sql;
update index.consolidated as a 
set GRANTS_3YP = case when a.GRANTS_3YP ^= . then a.GRANTS_3YP else (select GRANTS_3YP from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    GRANTS_3Y = case when a.GRANTS_3Y ^= . then a.GRANTS_3Y else (select GRANTS_3Y from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    RI_GEN = case when a.RI_GEN ^= . then a.RI_GEN else (select RI_GEN from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    FIFO = case when a.FIFO ^= . then a.FIFO else (select FIFO from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    YU_3Y = case when a.YU_3Y ^= . then a.YU_3Y else (select YU_3Y from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    POP_FLOWS = case when a.POP_FLOWS ^= . then a.POP_FLOWS else (select POP_FLOWS from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    COL = case when a.COL ^= . then a.COL else (select COL from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    IC = case when a.IC ^= . then a.IC else (select IC from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    DISTANCE = case when a.DISTANCE ^= . then a.DISTANCE else (select DISTANCE from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    MR_3Y = case when a.MR_3Y ^= . then a.MR_3Y else (select MR_3Y from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    MP = case when a.MP ^= . then a.MP else (select MP from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    DP = case when a.DP ^= . then a.DP else (select DP from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    RENT = case when a.RENT ^= . then a.RENT else (select RENT from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    DEATH = case when a.DEATH ^= . then a.DEATH else (select DEATH from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    MENTAL = case when a.MENTAL ^= . then a.MENTAL else (select MENTAL from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end,
    AGE = case when a.AGE ^= . then a.AGE else (select AGE from index.means as b where a.LGA = b.LGA) end;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query will take too much time, because you are updating 16 records at the same time and then you are using sub query in each SET.

My Advise is use JOIN (INNER/LEFT/RIGHT) , it seems that your sub query in each SET contains the same table `index.means`. Just put an identity to join your tables.